# JavaScript AJAX >> Python returning just Pythons code

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

When I try to execute Python code using JavaScript/AJAX, it does not show the response that I want, but the content of the Python file.

JS:

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
ajax.open("POST", "calc.py", false)
ajax.send(null)
alert(ajax.responseText)
```

Python (calc.py):

```
print "Hello World!"
```

`alert(ajax.responseText)` => 'print "Hello World!"'

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:
My "server" is basically just my laptop (elementaryOS x64 // Ubuntu) - Python and also PHP are installed, and It is being tested just on localhost.

Comment: Dunno, because you haven't provided any information. How are you serving the Python script?

Comment: Just as "calc.py" file in the same directory..

Comment: So how are you expecting this to work? You need a web server that executes Python files, and some means (WSGI, CGI) of running it.

Comment: And how do I do this? ( I'm running everything on my localhost/PC with Python installed)

Comment: The best way would be to use a framework. [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

To better help you, we would need some server info. Your server seems to be set up to display .py as plain text but what you want is to display the python output. Flask and Django, maybe others, are frameworks for this purpose, and not too difficult to install and learn. Daniel's comments are dead on, "...You need a web server that executes Python files, and some means (WSGI, CGI) of running it." My personal favorite for this is Django, great documentation, but I hear good things about Flask also.

Try one of these frameworks and tutorial:

Link for Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/install/

Link for Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Frameworks have a learning curve, but I have saved tons of time with Django in my projects. Good luck, and if you can tell us more about your server, someone may be able to get your set up running as you originally intended.